# building a dynamic query using where clause automatically changing numeric value to string type in SphinxQL query builder - laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, sphinx, where-in, sphinxql

$result is an array

```
$sphinx_ranked = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('*')->from('jobs')->where('id', 'IN', $result)->execute();
```

after executing I got error

```
[1064] index jobs: unsupported filter type '(filter-type-6)' on @id [ SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id IN ('57', '59')]
```

If I try this

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id IN (57,59);
```

Then this works. But I want dynamic values to be passed.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `$result` contain? is it an array of strings? it should be an array of numeric values. Seems the builder calls quoteArr on the list that calls ->quote() on each value. If strings it will string quote it)  - maybe use var_dump() on it to see if strings or numbers

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx require more accurate approach to control types of variables. Try next:

```
$sphinx_ranked = SphinxQL::create($conn)
    ->select('*')
    ->from('jobs')
    ->where('id', 'IN', array_map('intval', $result)) // <- int[] instead of string[]
    ->execute();
```